# Is it safe to remove an entry within the foreach loop of a mutable.Map in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know we should be cautious when removing an entry while traversing a collection in many languages like C++ or Java, but not sure if Scala makes any difference.
So is below code snippet safe?

```scala
val mutableMap: [String, List[String]] = ...
mutableMap.foreach { case (k, list) =>
  // do sth. to list
  if (list.isEmtpy) mutableMap -= k
}
```

What's the recommended way if I want to update the value for a `(k -> v)` mapping?

```scala
val mutableMap: [String, List[String]] = ...
mutableMap.foreach { case (k, list) =>
  mutableMap += (k, anotherList) // is this safe?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I think you need to return the updated list into a variable. So it would be val result = mutableMap.foreach { case (k, list) =>
  mutableMap += (k, anotherList) // is this safe?
} and then the updated map will be in result. Your solution works, but I think the more normal way would to map over it. So mutableMap.map( a => if( condition ) (a._1,a_.2) ) for example

Comment: So, yes I think it is "safe". Just looks a bit strange

Comment: It depends on your definition of safe. Those methods just _"work"_. But mutability is always a problem, other thread may be modifying or reading that map at the same time. Also, given there are usually simpler and more powerful methods to do what you want, your code may not ve as readable.

Comment: @GamingFelix The code snippet is just to highlight the key logic, and yes the updated list is returned in some way.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks! I just want to make sure it's safe in a single thread case. I'm aware of the race condition in a multi-thread context. I'm just worried deleting the entity inside the loop could break the iteration chain.

Comment: @user6502167 AFAIK it shouldn't, you can check the **scaladoc** just to be sure. In any case, are you sure you need a _mutable_ map? An _immutable_ map and a `filter` should do the job. And if you really need the _mutable_ one, please do not be that imperative using `foreach`, use `filterInPlace`.

Comment: Yeah, Luis is right that usually you'd seek to use an immutable data type in Scala. The prefered Scala way is to avoid using a mutable map.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez As I need to manage some cache inside an Akka actor (mutable member variable), I cannot find another solution besides a `var immutableMap = ...` or a `val mutableMap = ...`. And I just replaced the `foreach` with a `filter`.

Comment: @user6502167 Ok fair enough. The mutable map should be faster, but if you are in `2.12` it may be easier to use a `var` with an immutable one. Since cool methods like `mapInPlace` and `filterInPlace` were added in `2.13` - remember `filter` returns a **new** map.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the advice! Glad to know that.

Comment: @user6502167 In general within an actor, one should strongly prefer a `var` of an immutable collection to a `val` of a mutable collection, because in the former case, if the collection happens outside of the actor but in the same JVM, no practical violation of actor encapsulation happens.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve same with an immutable map like below;

```
val map: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map(
    "apple"     -> List(),
    "orange"    -> List(1),
    "banana"    -> List(1, 2),
    "pineapple" -> List(1, 2, 3),
    "kiwi"      -> List(1, 2, 3, 4)
  )

def doSomething(list: List[Int]) = ()

map.foldLeft(map) {
    case (acc, (key, value)) =>
      doSomething(value)
      if (value.isEmpty) acc - key else acc
  }
```

but I expect `doSomething` method is probably doing something that would count as a side effect. If you can afford using the [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/) library i would suggest you to do it in a way like below;

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

def doSomething(list: List[Int]): IO[Option[List[Int]]] = IO.pure(Some(list).filter(_.nonEmpty))

val program = map.toList
    .traverseFilter { case (key, value) => doSomething(value).map(_.map(key -> _))}
    .map(_.toMap)

program.unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the inbuilt method [filterInPlace](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#filterInPlace(p:(K,V)=%3EBoolean):MapOps.this.type) to remove the entries while treating.

```
val mutableMap: [String, List[String]] = ...

mutableMap.filterInPlace((k, list) => (list.nonEmpty))
```